# Sql query to find number of sequential number with specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequential

I have a table with two columns

```
Time 
Power
```

I want to write a sql query that show me in what periods the power was lower than 1000 and show the average power of that period.

For example

```
Time  power
1.    3000
2  4000
3. 500
4. 350
5. 200
6 1500
7. 2000
8. 200
9. 140
10 180
11  3000
```

Output

```
3-5  350
8-10  180
```

Comment: please add a few rows of your tabel and the code you already tried.

Comment: I edit it please help

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

SELECT CAST(MIN(Time) AS Nvarchar)+'-'+ CAST(MAX(Time)AS Nvarchar)Period,avg(Power) Average from [table] where Power < 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (MIN(Time))+'-'+(MAX(Time))Period,avg(Power) Average from table_name where Power < 1000
```